# Java - MongoDB best way to get first result with multiple queries

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to get the first Document based on multiple fields. I can get the first Document by doing:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("user", userId);
paymentsCollection.find(query).first();
```

That returns the user that matches the ID first. But what I'm wanting to achieve is it to return the first document based on multiple things like for instance:

```
                BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("lastUpdated", new BasicDBObject("$gt", date30DaysAgo));
                BasicDBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("status", "EXPIRED");
                BasicDBObject query3 = new BasicDBObject("user", userId);
```

How would I query them 3 different Objects all in one?

Here is a sample of what the documents look like:

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd7b2d90d9f9a1722956029"
},
"uuid": "92bb9960-3e3c-11eb-94e9-837449b33b23",
"dateCreated": {
    "$date": "2020-12-14T18:45:44.566Z"
},
"lastUpdated": {
    "$date": "2020-12-14T19:45:50.715Z"
},
"status": "EXPIRED",
"realValue": 1,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making use of [append](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#append-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-), which adds fields to a `BasicDBObject`.

Its usage for your case might look like this:

```java
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("user", userId)
    .append("status", "EXPIRED")
    .append("lastUpdated", new BasicDBObject("$gt", date30DaysAgo));
paymentsCollection.find(query).first();
```